# PHP расположения элементов массива или сочетания

Tags: php, алгоритм

Есть массив вида:

```
$arr = array(
             0 => array('id' => 1, 'title' => 'Point A'),
             1 => array('id' => 2, 'title' => 'Point B'),
             2 => array('id' => 3, 'title' => 'Point C')
          );
```

Нужно вывести в таком виде:

- Point A - Point B
- Point A - Point C
- .................
- Point B - Point C
- .................
- Point C - ......N

К примеру массив из 8 элементов, итого 28 перестановок. 
C<sub>n</sub><sup>k</sup>

Comment: задача ясна, проблема то ваша в чем? это вроде классическая задача комбинаторики, решения гуглится должны быстрее чем вы этот пост писали.

Comment: да вроде и нашел подобное решения https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567082/how-to-generate-in-php-all-combinations-of-items-in-multiple-arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_combinations($k, $xs)
    {
        if ($k === 0)
            return array(array());
        if (count($xs) === 0)
            return array();
        $x = $xs[0];
        $xs1 = array_slice($xs,1,count($xs)-1);
        $res1 = $this->get_combinations($k-1,$xs1);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($res1); $i++) {
            array_splice($res1[$i], 0, 0, $x);
        }
        $res2 = $this->get_combinations($k,$xs1);

        return array_merge($res1, $res2);
    }
```